# Include PDF as an image in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, pdf

When using `LaTeX` one can include a PDF as an image (this is usually done, e.g., with scientific papers, in which one can include a graph in PDF, so that it can be shown properly at different scales).

By using some tools like [remark](http://remarkjs.com/#1) and [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org) one can create web pages with some `LaTeX` insertion.
Now, suppose I am interested in including a PDF as an image, as I usually do with plain `LaTeX` files.

I have tried to include my PDF using the `<img>` tag, and everything was working, since I realized that this only works in Safari (since Safari considers PDFs as images too). This consequently does not work in other browsers, as Chrome / Firefox.

So, I tried to include the image with an `<embed>` tag, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html). However, what I obtain is a mini-PDF viewer inside the browser, with a grey frame all around the image I am including. I would instead like to include just the image, with no frames.

Is there a way of reproducing this behavior?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what type of framework or cms you use for your Homepage. But i guess you have to use sth like "imagemagick" to render your pdf files, like its done in wordpress or other cms systems.